# Markdown produces broken link

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, markdown-rendering

#### Input

The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/415257/20394 includes the markdown

```
...for the GWT widgets themselves: [Source for RadioButtonTest][1]
...
[1]: http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#A1edwVHBClQ/user/test/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RadioButtonTest.java&q=ButtonTest%20package:http://google-web-toolkit\.googlecode\.com "Source for RadioButtonTest"
```

#### Observed Result

This results in the HTML (line-breaks added for clarity)

```
...for the GWT widgets themselves:
http://google-web-toolkit\.googlecode\.com"
title="Source for RadioButtonTest">Source for RadioButtonTest</p>
...
```

This produces a partial tag including an un-escaped `'>'` character.

#### Expected Result

Replacing the `google-web-toolkit\.googlecode\.com` with `google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com` causes it to produce the expected HTML:

```
...for the GWT widgets themselves:
<a
 href="http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#A1edwVHBClQ/user/test/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RadioButtonTest.java&amp;q=ButtonTest%20package%3ahttp://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com"
 rel="nofollow"
 title="Source for RadioButtonTest"
>Source for RadioButtonTest</a>
...
```

#### Commentary

Backslashes (`\`) are not allowed in URIs so the input is partially invalid (since they are neither in the `unreserved` nor `sub-delim` character sets in RFC 3986), but their presence inside a URI should not cause broken tags in the rendered output.

I have not tested whether the rich text editor produces this escaping behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is long fixed; note that that answer is over three years old, so the HTML you saw was rendered way back then.

As you can see on the [revision page](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/415257/1), these days the HTML created from that Markdown is harmless. (Unlike the answers you see on the question page, the revision view is always rendered with *today's* Markdown converter.)

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  Perhaps I was failing to trigger a full markdown->HTML rerender in the preview, but I did try to make trivial changes to other parts of the question to force a rerender.